# Hibernate Enverse old data handling?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am using spring mvc and hibernate envers to audit my database, how can i deal with the old data to reduce the used disk space?

Should i have to backup the database every specific period and empty the audit database after backup? is there are a techniques to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a technique, described on Hibernate's manual, called partitioning:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#envers-partitioning

However it seems to tackle only the issue of indexing/query timing (it only creates 'buckets' of data that are most likely important (most recent ones)) and not the disk space itself.

If your old data is not strictly necessary for your application propper functioning, you could use the 'end revision date' as a *cut* on which rows you can wipe from your _AUD tables. This won't *break* envers, only won't give you the proper revision history.

Comment: I am using DefaultAuditStrategy not contains the end revision date, any replacement of the partitioning with the DefaultAuditStrategy?